# How can I exit while loop with "ESC" at any time/ C#

Tags: c#, loops

I have the following code in C#:

```cs
while (wechsel) 
{
    ProfDpDrv.MDPReadSlaveData(SlaveAddress, resetdiag, out dpData);
    newStatus = dpData.m_InputData[i]; 

    if (newStatus == 1) 
    {
        int debug = e.RowIndex;
        Dgv_Data_List.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Adresse"].Style.BackColor = Color.Green; //
        Dgv_Data_List.Refresh();

       wechsel = false; 
    }
}
```

Here I want to EXIT the loop with the <kbd>ESC</kbd> if `wechsel` still at true. I have no console by the way.

Comment: So what is this, a webapp, a console app, a win forms app, a micky mouse and the mouse factory app? "*I have no Console by the way*" - also explain this more

Comment: Use a KeyPress or KeyDown event in C#. 

Here’s a link to KeyPress event, for example. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=net-5.0

Comment: a win forms app

Answer (score 2):

Due to the fact, that we don't know where this code is running (WinForms, WPF, ASP, etc) except it is not a console it is hard to give you a concrete help.

A general advice to solve this issue, would be to create a `CancellationTokenSource` and give the `source.Token` to the long running method. This method can within the loop regulary check, if a cancellation was requested by checking `token.IsCancellationRequested` and then simply do whatever needed to leave a consistent state and exit the method.

And back to the beginning of my answer, it depends on the used interface you have to *hook* onto something to register a keypress and then calling `source.Cancel()`.

Answer (score 2):

I assumed that you are using WPF or WinForms.

Just subscribe to `KetDown` method on host window to capture all keys being pressed and then check if it's ESC and handle that appropriately, see code below:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private bool wechsel = true;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyDown += MainWindow_KeyDown;
    }

    private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key != Key.Escape) return;
        wechsel = false;
        txtInfo.Text = "interrupted by ESC";
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (wechsel)
        {
            txtInfo.Text = i++.ToString();
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }
}
```